# Gerar sequencia automática da api quando clicar no produto especifico

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, foreach

Eu tenho um portal do cliente, e nesse portal do cliente vai ter uma página de "minhas compras" aí lá vai mostrar os produtos comprados, e quando clicar nele vai aparecer o "rastreamento" desse produto com varias informações. Faço isso com dados de uma API.

`HTML` da página "minhas compras" :

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="flex-row row">


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" id="produtoUm">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="postagem.php" ><h3 class="produto"></h3> </a>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted status"></p>

<br>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" id="myButton" onclick="myButton">Acompanhar Pedido</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>

    <!-- <div="teste"></div>
      <a class="btn btn-info" onclick="Enviar1()" role="button">Acompanhar Pedido</a> -->

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" id="produtoDois">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="postagem.php" ><h3 class="produtoDois"></h3> </a>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted statusDois"></p>
                <br>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" id="myButton" onclick="myButton">Acompanhar Pedido</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>
```

**O produto vai ser colocado aí automaticamente pela api**
**Esses botoes eu fiz para ir pra página do "rastreio" do produto, mas como eu disse, sempre mostra apenas de 1 produto, e nao do produto que foi clicado**

```
HTML da página de rastreio:

    <div class="container">
           <div class="table-responsive">
               <table class="table table-status">
                   <thead>
                       <tr class="status">
                          <th class="thCenter">Status:</th>
                          <!-- <td id="info-status">ENTREGUE</td> -->

                       </tr>
                   </thead>
             </table>
           </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="oi">
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
          <thead>
                  <tr class="nome" id="testa">
                      <th class="thCenter ">Nome</th>
                      <!-- <td id="info-nome">THIAGO</td> -->

                  </tr>
                  <tr class="cpf tata">
                      <th class="thCenter">CPF</th>
                      <!-- <td>02798477425</td> -->

                 </tr>
                 <tr class="produto">
                      <th class="thCenter">Produto</th>
                      <!-- <td>COLCHAO GAZIN SUPREME COMPOSTO 138X188X21CM 1PL 660120 ./PR</td> -->

                </tr>
                <tr class="cidade">
                      <th class="thCenter">Cidade</th>
                      <!-- <td>MACEIO</td> -->
                </tr>
                <tr class="codproduto">
                     <th class="thCenter">Código do Produto</th>
                     <!-- <td>12819009</td> -->

               </tr>
               <tr class="codcliente">
                     <th class="thCenter">Código do Cliente</th>
                     <!-- <td>12819009</td> -->
               </tr>

                 <!-- Tabela adicionada apenas para mudar a cor do caminhão (table invisible) -->
               <tr class="cliente sr-only">
               <th class="thCenter">Quantidade</th>
               <!-- <td id="info-qtd">1</td> -->
         </tr>
              </thead>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Código de puxar a api:

```
var endereco = `http://apiaqui`;

$.ajax({
    url: endereco,
    crossDomain: true,
    complete: function(res){
        var meuJSON = JSON.parse(res.responseText);

        var a = [meuJSON];

        a.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                element[i]

                var adiciona = element;
                AdicionaNome(adiciona[i]);
                AdicionaCPF(adiciona[i]);
                AdicionaProduto(adiciona[i]);
                AdicionaCidade(adiciona[i]);
                AdicionaCodigoProduto(adiciona[i]);
                AdicionaCodigoCliente(adiciona[i]);
                AdicionaStatus(adiciona[i]);
                ActiveStatusImage(adiciona[i]);
                ActiveOnlyPostagem(adiciona[i]);
                adicionaClienteNaTabelaViagem(adiciona[i]);
                ActiveQtdViagem(adiciona[i]);

           }
        });
    }

});
```

E assim na página quando ele clicar no produto de "minhas compras" vai aparecer os dados do cliente e desse produto especifico. Mas como eu faço para quando clicar em certo produto na página "minhas compras" aparece só os dados desse produto, e nao de outro? 
Quando eu faço

```
AdicionaNome(adiciona[0]);
AdicionaCPF(adiciona[0]);
AdicionaProduto(adiciona[0]);
```

Mostra apenas os dados que está na sequencia 0. Teria uma forma mais pratica de fazer isso sem eu precisa fazer varias páginas com cada sequencia de produto?

Comment: você precisa adicionar em sua api o método que retorna apenas os dados de um único produto filtrando por seu `ID`

Comment: o ID dos produtos sao os mesmo, apenas é colocado um campo a mais para outra descrição do outro produto

Comment: Adiciona o seu html na pergunta.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Pronto

Comment: certo, me explica exatamente o que você quer fazer sem usar a palavra API, Acho você está confundindo um pouco a nomenclatura. API nesse contexto é apenas a aplicação que fica no servidor, recebe requests/posts e retorna as informações em JSON para serem aplicadas na tela pelo JavaScript

Comment: Eu vou tentar explicar detalhadamente...é assim... um cliente pode comprar um produto em uma loja, certo? Assim como pode comprar 2, 3,4...aí o cliente quer saber onde o produto dele está, certo? se ja foi encaminhado, essas coisas. Aí ele vai entrar no portal do cliente com os dados dele, lá vai ter uma página com todos os produtos que ele comprou, aí ele vai clicar em um produto para ver o "rastreamento" dele, aí nisso, eu queria fazer apenas uma página para todos esses produtos, e nao 1 página para cada produto que ele comprou. Entende?

Comment: O código de rastreio já está presente no retorno do ajax que você postou? Adiciona na sua pergunta a funtion `AdicionarProduto()`

Comment: Já sim, é o penúltimo código que eu coloquei na pergunta. Pq junto com o produto, vem outros dados como: nome, cpf,cidade...

Comment: Você precisa enviar um código do produto no Ajax para que a API retorne os dados desse produto.

Comment: Em vez de colocar os IDs "produtoUm", "produtoDois"... coloque o ID do produto que seja reconhecido pela API, e no Ajax vc envia esse código

Comment: Eu coloquei essas divs com esses IDs apenas para deixar visível ou invisível caso tenha nenhum produto a mais q um

Comment: E como eu colocaria pra enviar o código do produto para o ajax?